# Occasionally lonely or found on the floor A favorite use for me is not what I’m for What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Occasionally lonely or found on the floor
>
> A favorite use for me is not what I’m for

What am I?

Answer (score 4):

Probably wrong, but still fits

> Sock

Occasionally lonely or found on the floor

> Usually comes in pairs, tends to lie on the floor and after washing it's often alone, because the second gets lost in a black hole

A favorite use for me is not what I’m for

> My *second* thought was that it's Christmas time, so put your socks on the wall and hope they get filled with presents, which is a lot more fun than wearing them. My *first* though was, well, I don't know whether people really do that, but a stereotype from TV and memes is that it's *cough* lonely men doing the filling of the socks *cough*. Both could arguably be "favorite uses"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a

> sole

Because

> sole = lonely and
>  sole = bottom of foot or shoe

But I don't understand how the second line comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> a chair

Occasionally lonely or found on the floor

> a chair can be by itself or with other chairs, say around a table - and a chair is usually on the floor

A favorite use for me is not what I’m for

> I had to stand on a chair yesterday to reach something high. They are meant for sitting in though.